# Remove navigation property from POST parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm getting started with ASP.NET Core and EF Core 6. I'm trying to build a simple web api whith two models and an 1-n relationship between the models.

Model A:

```
public class ModelA
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ModelB> ModelBs { get; set; }
}
```

Model B:

```
public class ModelB
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }

    public Guid ModelAId { get; set; }
    public ModelA ModelA { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to create a ModelB by using the POST-endpoint of the ModelB-Controller, it expects me to pass the ModelA as well. If I do provide it, I get a duplicate key error because EF tries to create a new ModelA in the database, which causes a duplicate key error.

I must only use the ModelB-model as parameter for the post method and explicitly must not use any kind of intermediate model.

I would like to only use the ModelA id, not the entire ModelA object:

```
//Desired post-request
{
    "stringProperty": "value",
    "modelAId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
}
```

Making the ModelA reference nullable allows for post-requests as described above:

```
public class ModelB
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }

    public Guid ModelAId { get; set; }
    public ModelA? ModelA { get; set; }
}
```

But that feels wrong since an instance of ModelB must not exist without a reference to a ModelA instance.
Is there any way to achieve this without using DTOs or making the reference nullable?
I'm probably missing something trivial here.

Comment: can you try json ignore attribute ?

Comment: @SyMo7amed Thanks for your reply, that causes the example in swagger to look the way I want, but sending the request results in a validation error "The ModelA field is required"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you create a DTO(highly recommended, passing a whole another object just to show relationship is a waste of bandwidth and bad practice ) or not you will accept ModelAId from the user, not the whole object anyway so.
**Edit:**
if you want to trick the product owner. Just create a base class without ModelA prop and all the rest props in ModelB now make ModelB inherit this and add ModelA explicitly. Now create ModelBPost also inheriting from this and use this as a parameter for POST data this way the product owner knows the fields are exactly the same and you pass the verification error.
**Old Answer**

How about you get the model A fresh from DB and assign that to ModelB
like

```
public IAction PostModelB(ModelB modelB)
{
   modelB.ModelA = context.ModelAs.First(x => x.Id == modelB.ModelAId);
   //now since efcore is tracking this it know this object already exists
   context.ModelBs.Add(modelB);  
}
```

However, sometimes EFCore screws up and you get an already tracked error(which is quite unfortunate after so much time it still can't do it properly). If this happens(which it might since you are persistent on not using a DTO and accept a whole object just for relationship) you will have to set the navigation property null and only use the `ModelAId` property to insert the new record *or* you can get the instance which efcore holds:

```
var modelA = context.ModelAs.First(x => x.Id == modelB.ModelAId);
var trackedinstance = context.ChangeTracker.Entry(modelA)?.Entity ?? modelA;
modelB.ModelA = trackedinstance;
modelB.ModelAId = modelA.Id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That would definetely work. Unfortunately, I cannot get the ModelA field out of the request body without getting a validation error. Making the ModelA reference nullable does work, but this comes with the caveat that the reference is technically nullable, though in practice it won't be null since the ModelAId is required and EF is smart enough to determine that it is the Id for the ModelA reference.

Comment: Yes you're right, as I've specified you can make ModelA prop nullable and Id int so EfCore can only use Inner Join. If you don't want to do this, you will have to use a DTO I'm afraid.

Comment: @jbol14 if you want to trick the product owner. Just create a base class *without ModelA prop and all the rest props in ModelB* now make ModelB inherit this and add ModelA explicitly. Now create ModelBPost also inheriting from this and use this as a parameter for POST data this way the product owner knows the fields are *exactly* the same and you pass the verification error. Finally, after all this make sure to upvote and accept the answer XD

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :D PO is extremely knowledgable in software architecture and looks very closely. But simply making the reference nullable should work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should star to use DTOs on your project! For example, model B would have only the data necessary to create the item, i.e StringProperty and ModelAId, and inside of your controller, you would associate with the existing ModelA.

You can have a look on the entity framework on the link below.

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I failed to convince the product owner that we should use DTOs. His argument is that there must be a way to configure the necessary values since we don't have to pass an id for ModelB neither.

Comment: This is really out of normal procedure! In Fact to have good thing, and even evolve your API from v1 to v2 and keep all of this working, you would need one model to the user, and one DTO to the Business Logic. This approach is not really looking good.